# A DVD autostarts on my laptop and runs but not on my desktop

Tags: laptop, dvd, desktop-computer, mpeg, autostart

I have a DVD compatible drive on both my desktop and laptop. When I insert the DVD into my laptop, it recognizes it automatically and through clear.fi, plays the DVD. When I put the same DVD in my desktop DVD drive, it reads only the files and doesn't autostart a media program such as windows media player. I've been reading about MPEG decoding, could it have anything to do with that? My desktop runs Windows 7 64-bit as its primary OS.

Answer (score 4):

Type "autoplay" in the start menu's search box on your Windows 7 machine, and open the autoplay configuration options.

Now you can choose whatever default behaviour you want to correspond to "video files". There shouldn't be much more to it than that by the sounds of it.

Comment: Thanks! There's the default "ask me everytime" option, the take no action option, open folder to view files in Windows Explorer as well as import pictures and video on DropBox. There's no open to Run a "DVD Movie". Very odd.